# making confirmation when sending messages between files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that is supposed to send messages from content. js to popup. but it can't confirm if the message was sent or not.

so I wanted to add that content. Just send message1 to the popup. JS every 1 second, then when popup When JS receives the message, it sends a confirmation message to content. I want to stop it from sending message1 every 1 sec, but I can't make it work.
This is the way that I thought of if there is an easier way to do that I want to know, and all I found after searching was sending between background.js and content.js or popup.js but not popup.js and content.js.

Comment: 1) You can confirm it by receiving a response, see the examples in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). 2) Note the popup receives messages only when it's shown.

Comment: you mean that popup cant send messages

Comment: The popup can't do anything when it's not shown.